# ArcMap geoprocessing (merge and buffer) suddenly working very slowly

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, buffer, merge, performance

Typically, it works almost immediately but lately, anything I try to do (mainly merge or buffer) has begun to take an extremely long time to process.

I've tried clearing the cache and limiting the length of time that results are kept.

Comment: Try emptying geoprocessing history and/or create a new mxd document if you are using a saved one. Is it slow with the same inputs as before?

Comment: I would try BERA's suggestions particularly since you said anything you do is extremely long.  But if the input layers lack a spatial index I would add one for each input.  You might also check their geometry.

Comment: @BERA I have created a new mxd document and am currently trying to merge layers that I have already previously merged to test the speed. It is still working on the merge and taking far longer than it used to.

Comment: Has your data moved from local disk to a shared drive?